# Using a Msgbox to display items within a range

Tags: vba, excel

The idea behind this is to have an input area, and a display area. The input area holds values, and the display value shows them(All ready complete). The input area may have less than or more than what is being offered to be displayed. Here is a scenario;

```
----sheet3------    ------sheet4-------
DISPLAY            INPUTS
Name       Val     Name         Val
A8         B8       D8          E8        
1 x        -1     Oranges        5
2 x        -1     Peanutes       2
3 x        -1     Peaches        6
4 x        -1     Coffee         -1
                  Nuts           6
                  Corn           10
```

As seen, the display can only hold a total of four values that are not -1. We can just make this number 4 a fixed number in the code. I have functionality in place(countif formula) that fills the display first come first serve, but need functionality that will msgbox a input name, if there is no space for it in the display. -1 values represent no input. I need a message box that will display the inputs names which cannot be displayed. In this scenario, a message box of "Corn" as that is the only one that cannot be displayed. How could I go along of doing this with ranges instead of fixed cell numbers?

Here is a non working pseduo/written code example that I threw together to get a better idea how to do this with ranges. Range1 represents D8, while Range2 represents D13.

```
Dim i As Long, cnt As Long
cnt = 1
For i = Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("range1").count To Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("range2").count 'Get all items between.

If cnt <= 4 'if less what display can offer
If i != -1 then 'val is not nothing
cnt = cnt + 1 'increment how many items we have displayed
end if
else
msgbox Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A" & i).Value ' The value of I is incorrect as that is not the true range row number. Can you get the actual row of the range with something like .Rows?
end if
Next i
```

Comment: you're writing about "Sheet1" and "Sheet2" but your code is about "Sheet4": what's the truth?

Comment: I've updated it in case it threw you off. I'm only working on the input section, so using any sheet as you'd like is fine by me.

Comment: Why not a userform?

Comment: @PankajJaju I am generating a report. This is a very small snipped of the program I have assembled. I am only trying to print the name of values that are greater than 4 (aka can't be on display). I can do this with direct calls to cells, however, would like to do this with ranges so if I shift cells within excel, it won't break the vba itself.

Comment: @Brandon - Keep in mind that a `MsgBox` have a limit of 1024 chars only.

Comment: @PankajJaju Yes indeed. The names never exceed 20 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I have changed it so there is only one named range for simplicity. ie `range1` is D8:E13. (It's easy to change it back if you'd prefer)

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim i As Long, cnt As Long
    cnt = 1
    For i = Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("range1").Row To Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("range1").Row + Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("range1").Rows.Count - 1 'Get all items between.

        If cnt <= 4 Then 'if less what display can offer
            If Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("range1").Cells(i - Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("range1").Row + 1, 2) <> -1 Then 'val is not nothing
                cnt = cnt + 1 'increment how many items we have displayed
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("range1").Cells(i - Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("range1").Row + 1, 1).Value
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You sir deserve a golden star. I've been starting to use ranges as I have used direct cells in the past, causing full programs to completely crash from one minor altercation. Now if cells get shifted, ranges will move with it. Very nice technique with shifting to for loop through the sections. I'll sure be using this in reference for the rest of my report. Thanks!

Comment: You may want to double check the value of i as i is the row number, and not the value. This means "If i <> -1 Then" will never be successful.

Comment: Sorry, yes. Corrected. btw this will display `MsgBox`es for _all_ items after the fourth non -1 item (ie if you extended the list with another item with value -1 then this would also be displayed). If this is not what you wanted, then you'll need the same check around the `MsgBox` line as around `cnt = cnt + 1`

Comment: One last thing. I've updated your answer, as you forgot to limit -1's items from being printed, as they wouldn't be displayed in the first place. After you the edit gets pushed I'll mark you as the solved answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

you could try this

```
Sub main()
    Dim cnt As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim msgString As String

    With Worksheets("Sheet4")
        With .Range("D7", .Cells(.Rows.count, "D").End(xlUp))
            .Offset(, 1).AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="<>-1"
            For Each cell In .Resize(.Rows.count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                cnt = cnt + 1
                If cnt > 4 Then msgString = msgString & cell.Value & vbCrLf
            Next cell
            If msgString <> "" Then MsgBox Left(msgString, Len(msgString) - 1)
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```